# Search Keywords in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm setting up a new Search Center for our Intranet using MOSS and want to make heavy use of of Keywords and Best Bets.  However two questions about this have me perplexed and I would appreciate any help/guidance?

1)  If you assign a contact to a keyword/best-bet and set a review date, my understanding is that SharePoint will automatically send that contact an email alert when that time comes.  However in my testing just using my account as the contact I have never received one of these.  Am I doing something wrong?

2)  What permissions would a user need to edit/update a keyword they are the assigned contact for?  I assume too that if they have the rights to update one of them then they can probably unfortuantely update them all, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke with Microsoft about these questions and learned that there is no automated alert or built-in workflow that triggers when a keyword hits its review date.  Also only a site collection administrator can view and update a keyword.  If you want this type of functionality your only choice is to roll your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. I cannot get an alert sent on my systems - not really proof of anything though.
2. The keywords are stored in the site settings, so site collection administrator is going to required. They will also all be able to edit them.

However, you could easily create a list that allows people to add "keywords" and permission it so they can only edit thier own. Add an event handler to modify the actual keywords when an item is added or modified.

Comment: Nat, note that I discovered that keywords are not stored in the site collection but rather the SSP.  You can see this by taking a STSADM backup of the site collection and then restoring it on another place, for which you'll see the keyword collection will be empty.